# How to implement lazy fetching a list combined with a conditious get for one element of that list?

Tags: java, jpa, jaxb

We're setting up a DB with an object model for safes that have bill readers inside to put the bills in. This safe is stored in the Unit class and that unit has a list of placeholders for, let's say, 3 components. Components can change over time, but placeholders will stay connected to the same safe. So this unit has 3 placeholders with identifiers like 'left reader', 'right reader' and 'printer'. The actual component inside such a placeholder has the product type (for instance Mei reader ... or JCM reader ...) and a serial number.

Now, as the unit itself will be requested from the server side quite often as it is shown in one or more (pages of) portals (to see it's own serial number, location, how much money is inside, which users are allowed to log on to this safe, etc.) and components need not be known most of the time we want to lazily load them. The unit itself needs to know it's actual components (configuration) with serial numbers for components to be able to know / tell the back end when a component is exchanged during a servicing by a mechanic.

There is an intermediate table (placeholdercomponents) with placeholder FK, component FK and a datetime placed and a datetime removed.

Right now there is a Unit class that contains, besides a lot else, this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "unit", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Placeholder> placeholders = new ArrayList<>();

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "Placeholders")
@XmlElement(name = "Placeholder")
public final List<Placeholder> getPlaceholders() {
    return placeholders;
}
public final void setPlaceholders(List<Placeholder> pPlaceholders) {
    placeholders = pPlaceholders;
}
```

The placeholder class has this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "placeholder", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<PlaceholderComponent> placeholderComponents;

@XmlTransient
public List<PlaceholderComponent> getPlaceholderComponents() {
    if (placeholderComponents == null)
        placeholderComponents = new ArrayList<PlaceholderComponent>();
    return placeholderComponents;
}
public void setOrganizationUnits(List<PlaceholderComponent> pPlaceholderComponents) {
    placeholderComponents = pPlaceholderComponents;
}

@XmlElement(name = "Component")
public Component getCurrentComponent() {
    if (placeholderComponents == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        PlaceholderComponent placeComp = placeholderComponents.stream()
                .filter(pc -> pc.getDateTimeRemoved() == null)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
        if (placeComp == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return placeComp.getComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

And in the service there should be two possible calls getUnit & getUnitWithComponents. Now, if I remove the @XmlElement(name = "Component") annotation above getCurrentComponent() and do nothing with the placeholderComponents inside the getUnit call it works as expected, but getUnitWithComponents doesn't work (it works, but doesn't return the components inside the placeholders). When I leave the annotation getUnitWithComponents works as expected, but getUnit gives an error about not being able to lazily load the placeholderComponents as, apparently, JAXB wants to build the Component element even though the whole list isn't called in the service and therefore not loaded.

I can think of 3 possible 'solutions' working around this:

1. Remove the getCurrentComponent and make a separate call for retrieving the current component in a placeholder which would send a single component XML back
2. Make two different objects for Placeholder while both are for the same DB-table, using the one for getUnit (where the Component annotation isn't present) and the other for getUnitWithComponents (where the Component annotation is present).
3. Another option would be splitting into DAO's and DTO's as there might be more of those situations coming, but that splitting would take quite some time by now.

So the main question is: is there a way to get the components inside the unit XML for some calls and leave them out for most of the calls without a workaround? And if not, what solution would you chose? 1, 2, 3 or another one?